# Can I put a 20Amp breaker on my existing 15AMP garage circuit?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I bought a dust collector and I am trying to find out if I can run it together with the table saw at the same time on the existing circuit. Not sure what the 2x15 circuits are for (house built during the 60s but the electrical is more recent. No per room AC devices. 
The forth picture shows the inside wiring but it is made of collated pictures (the washer is partially blocking the electrical panel closed door and I can't take an one shot overall picture) I marked with red lines where I stitched the pictures 
Here are pictures of my electrical panel
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is a close up of the wires on the right side (from top to bottom, not fantastic pictures for the same reasons explained above) Maybe this can help you determine what wires I have and if I can install 20AMPS breakers at least for the garage (the circuit is on the left side but the wires seem to be the same)
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit:
Table saw Ridgid 3650
Dust collector : Harbor Freight 2HP 70 gallons dust collector

Comment: I am not seeing any traces of melting down plastic, no burnt plastic smell there or anything like this

Comment: Look closely at the cable going to the 40A downstairs range circuit.  Does the cable have both a white neutral and a bare ground wire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Don't try to run a saw and a dust collector on the same circuit

You seem to think a 20A circuit will magically support both. ***No, it won't***. You sink the time, energy and cost into getting that single 20A circuit, plug both in, and you'll get a *snap* for your trouble.  **Stop trying**.

You need a 15A circuit for the dust collector, and Bob's your uncle.   For the table saw, a [different] 15A circuit *might* work.   If the saw has a NEMA 5-20 plug (rotated neutral), then  you definitely need a 20A circuit including 20A wire.

Now if the saw has a standard plug but still trips a 15A breaker reasonably often, **and you are prepare to dedicate that circuit to this saw only**, then take a picture of the motor nameplate on the saw, and post it here in a new question asking "Based on this motor nameplate, can I bump this breaker? Canada code." There *might* be a magical exception.  Maybe.  There are some numbers that need to be crunched.  Don't go slapping in a 20A breaker on that hope. Capische?

### A 20A circuit absolutely requires #12 *copper* or #10 *aluminum*

You cannot simply slap a 20A breaker on any cable that uses #14 copper or #12 aluminum.   Remember, even if  you are able to exploit that magical exception, that only works on a circuit dedicated to one specific tool.

You can tell what  your cable is by reading the words printed on the cables for about 1 foot.  There's a lot there, but there should be something like 14/3 AWG or 14 AWG, and Copper, CU, Aluminum, or AL.

Given that the cable near the panel is in unfinished space, and garages often are too, you may be able to run new cables and then obtain new 20A breakers for those cables.  *This is the **normal** approach when acquiring new power tools.  It's part of the ritual*.

Check with your local EATON dealer (or ThreePhaseEel if you can post a picture of your panel's label), but it *appears at first glance* that your panel takes EATON type BQL breakers (or BQLT if you need double-stuffs).  These cost C$20 per space at Lowes, which figuring for exchange rate and VAT is probably about twice a common BR breaker.  They bolt down, so you must power down the whole panel to fit them.  But that's easy enough.

### "But Commander panels are *dangerous!"*

OK, let's think this through.  There are dangerous panels out there, but their troubles generally fall into 3 different areas.

- The bus stabs not having good contact, arcing and starting fires. *This panel uses bolt-down breakers, which makes this a complete non-issue*.
- The neutral and ground bars making poor contact with the wires for some reason.  *Later research proved much of this trouble was actually caused by screws not being torqued down to spec.  Because of this, US NEC now requires installations use a torque screwdriver.  In panels with suspect G/N bar problems, this is the best answer*.
- The breakers themselves being duff.  FPE and Zinsco got caught out cheating their UL listings.  I don't know why CSA (Canada's UL) delisted Commander panels, but they did. *The fix here is replace the breakers with reliable modern stock. That's not an option for FPE or Zinsco (the $80 Connecticut Electric replacement breakers are even worse than the originals)... but Eaton's BQL line is the replacement for Challenger, and it appears to be simply a repackaged BR breaker with a  boltdown flange instead of a stab clip. And, they are sanely priced.*

Comment: I will check the wires later today. I have a second circuit but I not sure if it has a ground wire. That one feeds the kitchen lights and the porch lights (1 bulb) and the lights that are to the left and the right of the garage entrance. The former owner did some patch work and run a cable through the ceiling of the porch and from there extended the cable (which is visible for this segment) to the garage (it enters the side wall of the garage, it pops up on the other side. inside the garage and from there it splits in two going out again on the front wall of the garage to feed the two lights

Comment: I could install a power outlet where the split is and plug the DC there -not sure which one needs grounding more, the TS or the DC. The other option is to use a cable extender from the basement kitchen

Comment: There is lots of factual evidende that the DC is fine on a 15A circuit https://www.lumberjocks.com/topics/48159

Comment: @MiniMe They both need grounds. BUT, you can "retrofit ground" by running a ground wire (alone) from an ungrouded location to a grounded location *whose path back to the panel is at least that ground's size*.   At least in the USA you can, we added that in NEC 2014, which was adopted by most states at this point.

Comment: Ok excellent idea, please have a look at this layout. Where you see "GFI" that is where the circuit enters the garage from the adjacent house. The panel is in the basement as you go north in the picture (distance is typical width of a canadian bungallow -25'?) https://i.imgur.com/B6wWhS3.png  so where you see the  first garage light, above the air compressor I could install a power outlet and get the ground from the other outlet that is just above the compressor ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the picture with the circuit breakers labeled is accurate, and going down to the picture of the inside of the panel where breaker 15 is located, it looks to me like that's 14 wire to the breaker.  If that's the cable to the garage, then the answer is NO.  The breaker on any 14 gauge wired circuit can not be greater than 15 amps.

Comment: Do I have any wire in that panel that supports 20AMPs ? How do you know which wire is 14 or whatever else size (gauge?)

Comment: If #15 is your garage breaker it's almost certainly 14 gauge wire based on the visual of it's diameter. However, it's easy to determine - inspect it. Compare it to the diameter of wire on your 20 amp circuits. 14 gauge isn't heavy enough to carry 20 amps. This means it has too much resistance for the potential load which means excessive heat and a potential fire. Using it would also be against code.

Comment: I just did a dry run, table saw and dust collector on the same circuit ....it was OK. I will see how it goes when it is loaded. That is peak amperage anyway, it might rarely hit that. the . Added the models of the power tools in the original post